# Explaining frequency[toupper(new_letter) - 'A']++;

Tags: c++, arrays

So I've been searching for a solution to a problem that one step involves counting the frequency of each unique letter. Everywhere I go has the same array incrementor. I haven't seen this form and don't fully understand it. I have attempted to find support documentation for the format but can't figure out what it actually does.I Can get it to work; however, I'm not sure what each peice represents.

Peice I'm having issues understanding is what's going on inside the brackets here.

```
frequency[toupper(new_letter) - 'A']++;
```

Where frequency is an array

an example from: [count number of times a character appears in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791426/count-number-of-times-a-character-appears-in-an-array)

**Algorithm:**

- Open file / read a letter.
- Search for the letters array for the new letter.
- If the new letter exists: increment the frequency slot for
  that letter: frequency[toupper(new_letter) - 'A']++; If the new
  letter is missing, add to array and set frequency to 1.
- After all letters are processed, print out the frequency array: `

  cout << 'A' +
     index << ": " << frequency[index] << endl;

any help understanding would be much apprecaited.

Comment: `frequency` is either an array of counters or a poorly utilized map (which could have been significantly better used). Either way, the "index" is a non-platform-independent calculation of subtracting the character encoding value of 'A' (usually ASCII) from the said-same-encoding value of the input character in an attempt to generate a 0-based index into the frequency array.

Comment: It should also be noted that this whole thing blows apart as soon as you feed it anything outside the index-calculation (like a space, a digit, etc). Ideally this is better served with a std::map<char, int> that guarantees a home for whatever input is being tossed into the ring.

Comment: @WhozCraig, it would blow up anyway when using UTF-8...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply an array. Maybe the part that is confusing you is `toupper(new_letter) - 'A'` what we do here is - we convert the letter to upercase and then subtract the ASCII code of `'A'` from the ASCII code of the result. Thus the result is a number in the range `[0-25]`. After that by adding this to `'A'` we get the origianl uppercase character. As for the rest of the algorithm - this is simply something like [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Comment: Thanks! that makes more sense. Did not know you could do that.

Comment: Keep in mind that characters are just represented by an integer (specifically a byte).  I find that looking at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) is very helpful when explaining this sort of problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this solution is not completely portable. It assumes that in the execution character set, the capital letters A-Z have consecutive values. That is, it assumes `'A' + 1` is equal to `'B'`, `'B' + 1` is equal to `'C'`, and so on. This is not *necessarily* true, but it usually is.

`toupper` simply converts whatever character is passed to it to uppercase. Subtracting `'A'` from this, given the above assumption, will work out the "distance" from `'A'` to the given letter. That is, if `new_letter` is `'A'`, the result will be 0. If it is `'b'`, the result will be 1. As you can see, the reason for using `toupper` was to make it independent as to whether `new_letter` was uppercase or lowercase.

This result (essentially the position of the letter in the alphabet) is then used to access the array. If `frequency` is an array of 26 `int`s (one for each letter), you will access the corresponding `int`. That `int` is then incremented.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an `array` (e.g. `int frequency[26];`) then we don't add to array - it is already there, but with a value of zero.

The `++` operator is short hand for `add one to the thing`, so

```
frequency[toupper(new_letter) - 'A']++;
```

is the same as:

```
frequency[toupper(new_letter) - 'A'] = frequency[toupper(new_letter) - 'A'] + 1;
```

Obviously, the short hand version is much easier to read, as there is much less repetition that has to be carefully checked that it's the same on both sides, etc.

The index is `toupper(new_letter) - 'A'` - this works by first making any letter into an uppercase one - so we don't care if it's `a` or `A`, 'c' or `C`, etc, and then subtract the value of first letter in the alphabet, `'A'`. This means that if `new_letter` is `'A'` the index is zero. If `new_letter` is `'G'` we use index 7, etc. [This assumes that all the letters are sequential, which isn't absolutely certain, and for sure, if we talk about languages other than English that have for example ä, ǹ, Ë or ê, etc as part of the language, then those would definitely not be following A-Z]

If you were to count the number of letters in a piece of text by hand, you could just list all the letters A-Z along the edge of the paper, and then put a dot next to each letter as you read them in the text, and then count the number of dots. This does the same sort of thing, except it keeps each count running as you go along.